# Dictionary.get: Dictionary does not contain key: EVI

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, dictionary, evi

I'm trying to write a script that calculates and retrieve EVI values from Sentinel-2 MSI in GEE then performs zonal statistics using points and export it .csv. I've written similar loop scripts for NDVI and it worked fine but this one keeps giving me the same error message.

Here is my code

```
// Load the shapefile as a feature collection
var region = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-gsehi/assets/2023_BG_traps_Zonal_v4");

// Define the start and end date for the year 2023
var startDate = '2023-01-01';
var endDate = '2023-12-31';

// Define the temporal window length as 1 week
var interval = 1;
var intervalUnit = 'week';
var intervalCount = 52;  // Number of weeks in 2023

// Define the cloud masking function
var maskCloud = function(image) {
  var QA60 = image.select(['QA60']);
  return image.updateMask(QA60.lt(1));
};

// Define a function to calculate EVI
var addEVI = function(image) {


  var EVI = image.expression(
        '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))', {
            'NIR': image.select('B8'),
            'RED': image.select('B4'),
            'BLUE': image.select('B2')
        }).rename("EVI");
  return image.addBands(EVI);
};



// Load the Sentinel-2 image collection and apply cloud masking and EVI calculation
var sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                            .filterBounds(region)
                            .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                            .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 20)
                            .map(maskCloud)
                            .map(addEVI);

// Function to sample EVI values at each point and time
var sampleEVI = function(feature) {
  var point = feature.geometry();
  var time = ee.Date(feature.get('collecti_date'));
  
  // Filter the image collection for the current time
  var image = sentinel2.filterDate(time, time.advance(interval, intervalUnit)).mean();
  
  // Sample the EVI value at the point location
  var EviValue = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: point,
    scale: 10 // Adjust scale as needed
  }).get('EVI');
  
  // Check if EVI value exists, set to null if not
  EviValue = ee.Algorithms.If(EviValue, EviValue, null);
    
  // Add EVI value to the feature properties
  feature = ee.Feature(feature); // Convert to ee.Feature
  feature = feature.set('EVI', EviValue);
  
  return feature;
};
// Map the sampleEVI function over the feature collection
var pointsWithEVI = region.map(sampleEVI);

// Export the feature collection with EVI values to Google Drive
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: pointsWithEVI,
  description: 'points_with_evi_2023', // Updated description to reflect EVI
  folder: 'NDVI_2023', // Specify the folder in your Google Drive
  fileFormat: 'CSV' // You can export to other formats as well, e.g., 'CSV', 'GeoJSON', etc.
});
```

Comment: Please paste the error message as text in the post rather in the title.

Comment: Can you set you set the `region` FeatureCollection as public so anyone can access it?

Answer (score 0):

You're going out of your way to try to replicate how null values are handled, but if it's null, you (usually) can't `get()` it.  Instead, just set the output of the reduceRegion onto the feature and be done.

```
   // Sample the EVI value at the point location
   var EviValue = image.reduceRegion({
     reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
     geometry: point,
     scale: 10 // Adjust scale as needed
   })
  
   return feature.set(EviValue)
```